# Prevent others finding me in Game Center

Tags: game-center

I don't want people to see me in Game Center. How can I prevent others from finding me?

People seem to locate me and I don't want them to. I would like to stay incognito but I can't find a privacy button to keep my name invisible.

Answer (score 1):

While in Game Center open your Account and change how others can contact you (or not contact you).

See example

[image: game center]

Comment: Over a year later, the "public profile" checkbox is now gone. Could you update this answer with the El Capitan equivalent?